# NTFS permissions on Windows file server

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

We are in the process of migrating a mess of a file server to a new server.

At the moment we have a lot of different shares and we are replacing these with a single share (for example "Shared" mapped to "S:" using Group Policy) with subfolders using access-based enumeration.

We have created a "Shared" folder on the data drive of the new server which has subfolders for each department and then subfolders for each location. We want to lock this down so users cannot add/delete/rename department or location folders.

For example:

```
D:\Shared (users should not be able to do anything in this folder)
D:\Shared\Facilities (users should not be able to do anything in this folder)
D:\Shared\Facilities\London (users should be able to do things in this folder including creating subfolders under London)
D:\Shared\Marketing (users should not be able to do anything in this folder)
D:\Shared\Marketing\New York (users should be able to do things in this folder including creating subfolders under London)
```

Basically users should only be able to do things at the location level.

We are not using permissions at all on the old file server ("Everyone" has full access to everything) and don't know what would be the cleanest way to accomplish this using NTFS permissions?

Comment: The cleanest method would be to assign each user group explicit permissions in other words anything except giving Everyone full access.  Each root folder should explicitly assign the permissions, child folders would inherit those permissions, obviously each folder should have an appropriate user group

Answer (score 0):

You can change advance security settings to deny specified permissions for everyone
This is available permissions :

- Traverse folder / execute file
- List folder / read data
- Read attributes
- Read extended attributes
- Create files / write data
- Create folders / append data
- Write attributes
- Write extended attributes
- Delete subfolders and files
- Delete
- Read permissions
- Change permissions
- Take Ownership

You can change that permission to deny everyone, for each folder.

Right click in folder, click properties, than security tab, click advanced, then change permissions, and UAC is show, click yes, then add, select principal, type "Everyone", change type to deny, and select specified permissions to deny